# A method in angular that simply closes the page when hit to a button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

To exit a window or Angular page I have created an Exit button in the .html. To make the button work I want to write a method in the .ts file that will help me simply close the page.
Note: I am using Angular11 and Bootstrap 4.

Help me write the method.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you share a piece of code you have tried first before asking the question like that. Anyways here's something you can do:

In Html:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" (click)="closePage()">Close Page</button>
```

In TS:

```
closePage(){
   window.close();
}
```

Comment: I had tried with window.close as the page opened with window.open, but yet the error comes that "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it"  Have No Idea, how is it even possible.